# I'm trying to get list of users under a group in the following pattern

Tags: linux, perl, unix, ksh

For example, AAA000 and BBB111 are the users under CARDS group....I'm trying to get an output in the following format.

```
AAA000 AAA000@pattern.com \
BBB111 BBB111@pattern.com \
```

I tried grep -i CARDS: /etc/group | sed 's/$/,/' | sed 's/,/@capitalone.com\n/g'
which gives me

```
cards:x:36082:CARDS@pattern.com
AAA000@pattern.com
BBB111@pattern.com
```

Any idea what else should I include in the command to get in to the format I need...?

Thanks,
Sam.

Comment: Just so I understand, youre trying to get 
<username> <username@email.com> 
from the /etc/group?

Comment: @wbt11a : Yeah, you are right....

Comment: @jaypal : Input is the users under CARDS group which looks like CARDS,AAA000,BBB111 from 'grep -i CARDS: /etc/group'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in awk:

```
awk -F, '/cards:/{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++){printf"%s %s@pattern.com\n", $i, $i}}' file
```

Input:

```
cat file
cards:x:36082:CARDS,AAA000,BBB111
```

Output:

```
AAA000 AAA000@pattern.com
BBB111 BBB111@pattern.com
```

Comment: :It did not worked but I tweaked your code a lil bit to get the output...thanku... grep -i CARDS: /etc/group|awk -F, '/cards:/{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) print $i,$i"@pattern.com \\"}'

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your input is like this:

```
$ cat file
cards:x:36082:CARDS,AAA000,BBB111
```

You can do:

```
$ perl -F, -lane 'if(/cards:/){print "$_ $_\@pattern.com" for (@F[1..$#F])}' file
AAA000 AAA000@pattern.com
BBB111 BBB111@pattern.com
```

- We use `,` as field separator (defined by `-F,`).
- Using `-a` option splits our entire line on `,` in an array defined by `@F`.
- We test if the current line is the line you want to parse by doing `if(/cards:/)`.
- If it is we print every element of the array starting from second index (`@F[1..$#F]`) till the very last. This is because our first index would have the value `cards:x:36082:CARDS` which you don't need.

Comment: Hi Jaypal, this is working. But what if I want to use the command given by you on a output from grep command..which is..................grep -i cards : /etc/group | "your command"

Comment: You don't need to pipe this to `grep`. This one looks at lines having `cards` (`if(/cards:/`) which is basically what your group is doing. Just replace `file` with `/etc/group` and you should be all set.

Comment: Hey Jaypal..Thanks for the script, it is giving exactly what I'm looking for. It would be great if you give me an idea what this part of the script is doing?? ..... for (@F[1..$#F])}

Answer (score -1):

Found command using grep and awk...........

```
grep -i CARDS: /etc/group|awk -F, '/cards:/{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) print $i,$i"@pattern.com \\"}'
```

Thanks for the help guys.

Comment: It worked fine.....but none of us here are not familiar with PERL, so they needed something with UNIX commands.